# Getting a call hierarchy for Java methods including other projects in a repository

Tags: java, refactoring

I have an Eclipse workspace with about ten projects, all of them checked out from a CVS repository that easily contains a hundred projects more.
I can now highlight a method and bring up a call hierarchy (usually with CTRL-ALT-H) showing all classes in my workspace that call this method.

Is there a possibility to get a call hierarchy that checks not only my workspace projects, but also the resources from my repository? I'd like to kick out some legacy methods and I want to make sure that none of our projects still depend on them.

BTW, non Eclipse solutions are also welcome of course.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `CTRL+H` to bring up the Java Search dialog you have the option of selecting the scope: either "Workspace" which covers all projects in your workspace  , or "enclosing project" which is just the current project.

You want to make sure "Workspace" is selected which is probably what you want.  The results are then listed in the Search View

Comment: This will only include the projects in my local workspace, but I want the search to include projects in a specific CVS repository.